# display the arraylist data on UI as soon as something is added using java

Tags: java, arraylist, feed

What I am trying to do is implementing a news feeds kind of functionality.. so I have a listener which will call a function as soon as something is posted by the user and that function will give me the post and will store it in an ArrayList..

Now I want to display that post on my UI.. I can't find any perfect way to do this.. I don't want to call the method or send the request every 5 or 10 seconds from my UI to get the contents in the list.. What I want is as soon as the list is updated with the new post, it should be displayed on the UI..

Please help me on this and let me know if there is any additional information required..

Comment: You need some kind of observer pattern. The UI would register interest with what ever is updating the list and when updated, it would notify all registered listeners

Comment: with observer pattern I am able to get notification that my list is changed but I am not able to push the data to the UI as soon as list is changed.. so how to push the data is my ques..

Comment: Your question lacks context to generate a viable answer. How is the UI and the list separated? What is the UI (Swing/JavaFX/web)?

Comment: UI is a jsp.. I am using Spring framework but that is not mandatory.. it is a java based web application